# jquery The codes after slideDown() don't execute

Tags: jquery, slidedown

jquery code:

```
$('#loading').slideDown('slow');
alert("go");
```

In my case, alert() function didn't call, which means that the codes after slideDown() don't execute. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery lib loaded properly?

Comment: please add this as a comment and not as an answer